# Error when trying to run test in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I try to run some tests but somehow spring gets confused and I get the error below that appears to be some clash between some beans that Spring tries to instantiate. Anyone any ideas?

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:408)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.resourceHandlerMapping(Lorg/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper;Lorg/springframework/util/PathMatcher;Lorg/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManager;Lorg/springframework/format/support/FormattingConversionService;Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceUrlProvider;)Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping;

The method's class, org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/test/stuff/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.13/spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: file:/home/test/stuff/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.13/spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar
    org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport: file:/home/test/stuff/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.13/spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration

2021-12-16 19:46:21.564 ERROR [cc-task-allocation-backend,,,] 5484 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5ef5c734] to prepare test instance [eu.europa.ec.cc.taskallocation.services.RuleServiceUniformDistTest@61d4171d]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
```

Comment: Can you post your pom file (or build.gradle) and add it to your question, It looks for me like a dependency management issue.

Comment: Actually it was indeed a dependency management issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dependency management issue as the org.junit.jupiter dependencies were overwritten by a starter.

Comment: Can you provide the solution please?